# Set/Change the source of image in C# Gtk project, using MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, bitmap, gtk, ubuntu-14.10

I added an image element into my Gtk project.

> [image]

How can I set/change the source of this image element?

This is the content of `MainWindow.cs`:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{   
    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

In `MainWindow` method, `this.image1` seems to be the image element that I added. It doesn't contain `Source` property or any `set...` method that is related to setting the source.

So, how can I change the source from code behind? Is it possible to pass a `Bitmap` object directly?

Using MonoDevelop 4.0.12, on Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `Pixbuf` property works fine:

```
this.image1.Pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf ("/home/whoami/Pictures/1.png");
```